# jQuery shadows for rounded corners

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the CurvyCorners for my rounded corners at the moment.  I'm also using the shadow plugin from http://eyebulb.com/dropshadow/.  The problem is the dropped shadow is a box, whereas the element above it has rounded corners.  Any suggestions on getting a rounded corner shadow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corners plugins are typically hacks performed with multiple div tags or SVG rendering inside your original div.  The original div is still a square so that's what the drop shadow is going to render as.

You're trying to do too much with plugins and have basically reached the limit of what you can do with them.  I'd suggest going the old fashioned route and create some PNG images and refactor some of your html to achieve the effect.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as such. Anyone know of a plugin which does border images well?

Comment: You're abusing the use of plugins.  This sort of html rendering should be done server side when possible since you're site will deteriorate heavily if javascript is turned off.

Comment: Yes you can.  How do you think the plugins are creating the shadow?  They're wrapping your target divs in CSS and HTML.  You can do this manually very easily (header, body, footer graphics) then set the div as movable.